# Python3 print stdout flush not picked up by Node.js subprocess.stdout

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, stdout, child-process

As I understand it, `subprocess.stdout.on('data', ...)` fires every time stdout is flushed.

I have the following NodeJS code:

```
const cp = require('child_process');

const subprocess = cp.spawn(`python3`, [`main.py`]);

subprocess.stdout.on(`data`, (data) => {
    console.log(`Got: ${data.toString()}`)
})
```

And in the same folder, `main.py` containing:

```
import time

for i in range(5):
    print(i, flush=True)
    # time.sleep(1)
```

If the `time.sleep(1)` line is uncommented, the NodeJS code runs as expected, showing that flush indeed fires the stdout data listener, giving

```
Got: 0
Got: 1
Got: 2
Got: 3
Got: 4
```

However, when the line is commented, the behavior is inconsistent, with the listener firing once/twice instead of four times.

Is this because, in Python, the flushing did not complete before the next print comes and writes to the stdout buffer?

(Context: I am using this to listen to progress of a Python program (via stdout), and my flushes aren't picked up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this because, in Python, the flushing did not complete before the next print comes and writes to the stdout buffer?

Yes.

Well, it's a reader effect, rather than a writer effect.
You certainly can't rely on the reader seeing timing-induced
record boundaries with racy code like what you posted.

You have a pipe connecting child to parent.

Child writes a buffered `'0\n'`,
calls write(2),
and moves on.
Node was blocked on I/O, waiting on an empty pipe.
The write(2) unblocks node, and it consumes **at least** two bytes.
However, on another core the child has been busily issuing two-byte 
writes and arranging for blocked readers to become schedulable.
This involves very little work.
There's a good chance the parent has not finished dealing with
the first two bytes by the time the child has written its sixth byte.
So the parent reads batched chunks containing multiple lines.

There's at least two ways for parent to be in sync with child.
The child can *promise* to always write a single newline-delimited
record, as it does here. And then parent would only read up to the
delimiter when processing a newly available record.
Or child could promise to write (n, buf) pairs, where `n` tells
us the buffer has exactly that many bytes.
And again parent would do record-oriented reads.